# Minimum queens to reach $8 \times 8$ squares as a graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

A homework problem asks

> What is the minimum number of queens to reach all squares on a $8 \times 8$ chess board?

We are expected to solve this by somehow casting the problem as a graph problem (e.g. Minimum Spanning Tree, Vertex Cover, Independent Set, ...)

How would you reduce this problem to a graph problem, and which graph problem is the most straightforward to reduce this to?

(My first try at this problem was to reason that the number of different squares that a queen can reach is at most $\small 8 + (8-1) + (8-1) + (7-1) = 28$. This is from assuming $8 \times 8$ squares and choosing to place the queen at one of the $4$ center squares. I don't know if this approach can lead to a solution.)

Comment: Looking pretty NP to me, so independent set, vertex cover, etc. are your viable options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph theoretically, you are looking for the *[domination number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set)* of the graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V$ is the set of squares, and with two squares adjacent if a queen can legally move from one to the other.

Comment: That term is new to me. I took a glance at the link and the problem of finding the *domination number* looks to be the same as a problem which goes by the name VERTEX-COVER.

Comment: Not quite. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539174/vertex-cover-vs-dominating-set

Comment: Ah thanks for the correction (although the link isn't really what made the difference clear to me). Every vertex must be in or adjacent to the dominating set, but a dominating set need not have every edge incident to it.

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me and was how I approached my homework problem, but it didn't quite give me enough to solve the problem? Giving a $3$ to $5$ line algorithm that searches for the dominating set would be a huge improvement to this answer. By trial and guessing, I found a solution with $5$ queens, but that itself does not prove $5$ is the minimum solution possible.

Comment: Well $5$ *is* the correct answer, but it appears the only proof that $4$ isn't enough is by computer search. See discussion here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30330/is-there-a-good-argument-for-why-you-cant-place-4-queens-which-cover-a-chessboa  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145525/algorithm-to-solve-the-n-queens-domination-puzzle

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know the answer, the problem can be solved by modelling it as a set cover problem.

- The board can be modelled as $B:=\{(a,b)\,|\,1\leq a,b\leq 8\}$.
- For each square $(a,b)\in B$ let $r(a,b)\in 2^B$ be the set of squares, reachable by a queen positioned at $(a,b)$ within one move.
- Let $S=\{r(a,b)\,|\,1\leq a,b\leq 8\}$.

Now, we obviously have $\bigcup S = B$. WHat you're looking for now, is a minimum cardinality cover $C\subseteq S$ such that $\bigcup C = B$.